# BIRT one dataset per Page

Tags: birt

I want to create a BIRT Report with the Report Designer. (I am new to that..)
I can insert some values from a Dataset and can display it easily.
But now, I want to have a MultiPage-Report.

I have a Datasource (XML) with four or more DataSets - and I want to have (every page has the same header and same style) one dataset per Page.

The Data Binding Expression is by now dataSetRow["xxx"] - but how can I create a four-page-Report with same headers on every page and different dataset displaying on every page? - Maybe is there a function like "nextDataset" - or a checkmark to make a multi-page report with the length of the datasets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dataset in independent from the layout.

To show the rows from a dataset, you need (except for single-row datasets) a List item or a Table item, which is bound to the Dataset.

You can use the page break properties of the layout items to control page break.

Example:

E.g. if you have 4 datasets D1, D2, D3, D4, then you'll need 4 List or Table items T1, T2, T3, T4.
Set "Page break before" to "Always" for T1, T2, T3, T4 to make sure that each table starts on a new page.